# PicKit 1 and mplab

Tags: mplab, microcontroller, pic

When I try to use the PicKit 1 in MPlab for the PIC 16F913, it doesn't allow me to program the chip using my programmer, even though it has ICSP, I currently have to just pick some other programmer, compile my code and then use I think it's called Pic Kit Classic v1.74

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I would really like to skip the other step and do everything through MPlab since I have it open already!

The crazy thing is that the Pic Kit 1 is listed as a programmer for the 913, so I would think that MPlab should already know this.

Comment: Do you have access to a PICkit 2, the currently best supported PICkit - and does it work properly?

Comment: Nope, only the pickit 1,

Comment: Do you have the latest version of MPLAB?

Comment: pickit 3 treats me very very well. And the program time on large files is an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: At the time it was the latest mplab, I'm not sure what it is right now, I would have to check and I'm not at home. I haven't had large files just yet so fortunately time to program isn't a biggie.

Answer (score 1):

I have a PICKIT2 and there are some devices that it can program if you use the standalone PICKIT2 software but which it can't program from within MPLAB. It looks like the situation is the same for your device with pickit1.

If you look at the release notes for MPLAB it has a file for supported devices (On my machine it was stored at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microchip/MPLAB IDE/Readmes/Device Support.htm). That file indicates that specific PIC device is NOT supported for programming with a PICKIT1 using MPLAB.

And yet the PICKIT1 documentation does indicate that device is supported for programming.

Does the pickit1 come with a standalone programming program like pickit2 does? If so you can probably use that to upload the .hex file to it

Comment: Yea I have to use the PicKit programmer listed above, I just don't understand why mplab won't support, but it sounds like even pickit2 has the same issue.

Comment: Ah right.. Well, I suspect microchip are the only people who'd know that.

Answer (score 0):

I would upgrade to the PicKit2. It's only $35 and it adds some extra features that the PicKit 1 doesn't have. It will work in MPLab or from the command-line.

Comment: I guess my problem is that Microchip says I can program chip x, but mplab says I can't so I have to do a workaround, had I known that PicKit 2 was better at the time I bought this I would have bought it, but i've already sunk the $35 on this programmer when I did, I have a friend who has a PicKit 2, and I've considered just buying the parts and building one, but havn't spec'd it out yet.

Comment: The PICkit 1 only supports a very small number of devices, IIRC. It's not really intended as a programmer, it's more of a little evaluation kit.

Comment: @onaclov2000 - in my experience, buying the parts and building one is almost always a net loss in any project, either in time or money, even assuming you don't make mistakes.  The only exception to that is when learning things.  If your goal is to program chips, I'd get the PICKit2 or 3.